# Floating platform isn't on high enough in the Lumos challenge, gap can't be crossed

Tags: hp-and-the-philosophers-stone-pc

After learning the Lumos spell Harry proceeds to a challenge map. [In walkthrough videos](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Harry%20Potter%20and%20the%20Philosopher%27s%20Stone%20PC%20lumos) it can be seen that the last platform created with the spell is at the same height as others, but in my game on the ground level:

[image: Lumos challenge issue]

Harry can't reach the doorway (upper middle in the image) by jumping from the edge of either podiums.

The last platform floating correctly in the air (from a [walkthrough video](https://youtu.be/YoG05S4WoFQ?t=11m47s)):

[image: Lumos challenge]

I have reloaded my save and restarted the game. Sadly the progress is saved in one slot and because the game saved in the middle of this challenge the level can't be fully reseted. Can the issue be solved without starting a new game?

Comment: `pc` in the tag is mandatory because early Harry Potter games have completely different versions for some platforms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you're not the only one to encounter this problem. According to [this GameFAQs thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/516702-harry-potter-and-the-sorcerers-stone/51376599), you can bypass this by using a cheat:

> Type in `harrydebugmodeon` and do a super jump. You'll be able to find the codes on the cheats section for this game.

So you type `harrydebugmodeon` to enable cheats. Then you type `harrysuperjump` to increase jump height. Once you've reached the platform, you can type `harrynormaljump` to set your jump height back to normal. You would then hit <kbd>F7</kbd> to disable cheat/debug mode.

I also see people talk about running the game in various compatibility modes, but that doesn't seem to solve this particular problem reliably.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the `harrysuperjump` command only executes a super-jump instead of modifying the jump length. The cheat can also be used without debug mode, by typing during gameplay.

Comment: I see. It wasn't clear on the page exactly how these cheats were meant to be used.

Answer (score 2):

For other people encountering this:
Don't break the 2 vases that you see at the bottom of the 3rd platform.
Breaking these causes the platform to be stuck at a lower position. I think this only occurs on modern PC's because the pieces broken from the vases are still floating in mid-air, on old PCs with windows98 or windowsXP they should disappear.
I've played through the entire game and that seems to be the only place where those floating pieces are causing issues.